# Finding the inverse of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations

Let $A:P_3 \to P_3$ be linear operator such that $$Ap(x)=\int_0^1p(x+t)dt$$ where $p \in P_3$. Find $A(e)$ if $(e)=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ and $A^{-1}(2x-x^3)$

I just started learning about linear operators and I got stuck in this problem.
 I was able to find  $A(e)$ 
$$ A(e)=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \frac12 & \frac13 & \frac14 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \frac32 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

But I don't know how to find the inverse $A^{-1}(2x-x^3)$. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I don't know how to find the inverse $A^{-1}(\color{blue}{2x-x^3})$.

**Hint**

Now that you already have $A(e)$, this comes down to solving:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \frac12 & \frac13 & \frac14 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \frac32 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 a \\ b \\ c \\ d
    \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue}{ 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ -1}
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Finding $A^{-1}(2x-x^3)$ comes down to figuring out which polynomial is mapped to $2x-x^3$ by the operator $A$. Write $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$ and this comes down to solving the system above. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,1%2F2,1%2F3,1%2F4%7D,%7B0,1,1,1%7D,%7B0,0,1,3%2F2%7D,%7B0,0,0,1%7D%7D%7B%7Ba%7D,%7Bb%7D,%7Bc%7D,%7Bd%7D%7D%3D%7B%7B0%7D,%7B2%7D,%7B0%7D,%7B-1%7D%7D) to check.

Comment: Thank you very much I understand now